# How to copy HTML code into a text file using PHP

Tags: php, html, file, invoice

My company uses an invoice software I've made. It's a simple page that copies input from fields, checkboxes and some dynamic table with Javascript into a new page with A4 CSS so it can be printed or sent via mail as PDF.

Now I have to start on the second feature: open an invoice. I have thought of one way I could make this.

When a new invoice is made and input is copied into the other page, to also copy all the HTML from the form in which all the inputs are into a text file with PHP - and later when a user "opens" an invoice, it just opens the file which just copies all the HTML code.

I don't know how to copy part of the code into a text file. If you also know an easier, better way please tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).

Before you render anything out to the browser do

```
ob_start();
```

after you do your rendering get the html content.

```
$html = ob_get_contents();
```

then to send it to the browser do.

```
ob_flush();
```

Then with the $html you can save to file, database or whatever works for your use case

Comment: This will copy all html from the page? So then I can copy all from $html to a text file?

Comment: That's what it does. I use it a lot for confirmation emails. Show on screen and use in mail body.

Comment: Sounds good. Last question -- ob_start(); should be in the start of the page in which the invoice is made or the page where the inputs are?

Comment: ob_start just starts capturing the data so put it before you start outputting what you want to save and do the ob_get_contents() right after you output it. If you wanted the entire html page the ob_start should be before any echo statements or html.

Comment: For example if you wanted to capture a certain table in your code you would do: `ob_start(); echo "<table>"; /* everything else to build your table */; echo "</table>"; $table = ob_get_contents();